# Is there a way to get user declared variables in PHP?

Tags: php

**get_defined_vars** is about to (citation):

> return a multidimensional array containing a list of all defined variables, be them environment, server or user-defined variables

well, for my debugging task, I need only those user-defined. Is there php-built-in or supplement function?

EDIT:
Ok I didn't made clear what exactly I was after, here is little example:

```
<?php
/*
this script is included, and I don't have info
about how many scripts are 'above' and 'bellow' this*/


//I'm at line 133
$user_defined_vars = get_user_defined_vars();
//$user_defined_vars should now be array of names of user-defined variables
//what is the definition of get_user_defined_vars()?

?>
```

Comment: do you mean user defined vs. declared in a class definition?

Comment: what's a user-defined var? one that you directly defined in your own scripts? how could PHP tell between that and a var defined in some external file you required/included?

Comment: no, not about class vars, I need vars defined in global scope

Comment: User-defined implies that app I'm debugging has these vars declared somewhere

Comment: What about `$GLOBALS` array ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about a little array manipulation?

```
$testVar = 'foo';
// list of keys to ignore (including the name of this variable)
$ignore = array('GLOBALS', '_FILES', '_COOKIE', '_POST', '_GET', '_SERVER', '_ENV', 'ignore');
// diff the ignore list as keys after merging any missing ones with the defined list
$vars = array_diff_key(get_defined_vars() + array_flip($ignore), array_flip($ignore));
// should be left with the user defined var(s) (in this case $testVar)
var_dump($vars);

// Result: 
array(1) {
    ["testVar"]=>string(3) "foo"
}
```

Comment: This answer best fits my needs. Thanks.

Comment: @Crisp You are missing some [predefined variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php).

Comment: this answer is hugely misleading as it is missing all variables defined in the local scopes which means 99% of variables in the properly organized code

Answer (score 18):

Yes you can:

```
<?php
// Start
$a = count(get_defined_vars());

/* Your script goes here */
$b = 1;

// End
$c = get_defined_vars();
var_dump(array_slice($c, $a + 1));
```

Will return:

```
array(1) {
  ["b"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Comment: what will happen with session variables and variables that are sent in like $_POST and so on?, i like your idea though hence the upvote

Comment: @EyalAlsheich Everything that is defined before `$a` (in this example) will be hidden. $_POST is defined before execution of any user code. For sessions it depends if you use `session_start();` or session auto start.

Comment: This is really neat. Best answer here.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://online-source.net/2011/08/12/get-user-defined-variables/) seems like a cool solution to your problem:

```
<?php
// Var: String
$var_string = 'A string';

// Var: Integer
$var_int = 55;

// Var: Boolean
$var_boolean = (int)false;



/**
 * GetUserDefinedVariables()
 * Return all the user defined variables
 * @param array $variables (Defined variables)
 * @return array $user_variables
 */
function GetUserDefinedVariables($variables){;
    if (!is_array($variables))
        return false;

    $user_variables = array();

    foreach ($variables as $key => $value)
        if (!@preg_match('@(^_|^GLOBALS)@', $key))
            $user_variables[$key] = $value;

        return $user_variables;
}


echo '<pre>'.print_r(
                        GetUserDefinedVariables(
                                        get_defined_vars()
                                                ), true).'</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: This will hide all user defined variables starting with underscore and starting with GLOBALS.